# Tensorflow error message "Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient.", given by AdagradOptimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I realize that somewhere in my code some dimension of one of my tensors is wrong from the main error message

```
ValueError: Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient.  Forward operation: SegmentMean.  Input index: 0. Original input shape: (126, 80).  Calculated input gradient shape: (126, 80)
```

I also want to know exactly how to interpret the whole error message because I feel it may give me more insight to what exactly is going wrong.

Here is the full error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in set_shape(self, shape)
    534           dim_list,
--> 535           unknown_shape)
    536     except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 504 and 126. Shapes are [504,80] and [126,80].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
    661               try:
--> 662                 in_grad.set_shape(t_in.get_shape())
    663               except ValueError:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in set_shape(self, shape)
    537       # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
--> 538       raise ValueError(str(e))
    539 

ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 504 and 126. Shapes are [504,80] and [126,80].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e8feccf3b5a2> in <module>()
     57   # that contribute to the tensor it is passed.
     58   # See docs on `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize()` for more details.
---> 59   optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)
     60 
     61   # Compute the similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in minimize(self, loss, global_step, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, name, grad_loss)
    412         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
    413         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops,
--> 414         grad_loss=grad_loss)
    415 
    416     vars_with_grad = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py in compute_gradients(self, loss, var_list, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, colocate_gradients_with_ops, grad_loss)
    524         gate_gradients=(gate_gradients == Optimizer.GATE_OP),
    525         aggregation_method=aggregation_method,
--> 526         colocate_gradients_with_ops=colocate_gradients_with_ops)
    527     if gate_gradients == Optimizer.GATE_GRAPH:
    528       grads = control_flow_ops.tuple(grads)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
    492   with ops.get_default_graph()._lock:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    493     return _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops,
--> 494                             gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
    495 
    496 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in _GradientsHelper(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
    667                     "Original input shape: %s.  "
    668                     "Calculated input gradient shape: %s" %
--> 669                     (op.name, i, t_in.shape, in_grad.shape))
    670             _SetGrad(grads, t_in, in_grad)
    671         if loop_state:

ValueError: Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient.  Forward operation: SegmentMean.  Input index: 0. Original input shape: (126, 80).  Calculated input gradient shape: (126, 80)
```

Here is the code section which produced the error

```
batch_size = 126
embedding_size = 80 # Dimension of the embedding vector.
cbow_window =2
valid_size = 16 # Random set of words to evaluate similarity on.
valid_window = 100 # Only pick dev samples in the head of the distribution.
valid_examples = np.array(random.sample(range(valid_window), valid_size))
# Random set of words to evaluate similarity on.
num_sampled = 64 # Number of negative examples to sample.

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default(): #took out " , tf.device('/cpu:0')"

  # Input data.
  train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
  train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
  valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

  # Variables.
  embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))
  softmax_weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                         stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(embedding_size)))
  softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

  embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset) #train data set is

  segments= np.arange(batch_size).repeat(cbow_window*2)

  averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean( embed, segments, name=None)

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.sampled_softmax_loss(weights=softmax_weights, biases=softmax_biases, inputs=averaged_embeds,
                               labels=train_labels, num_sampled=num_sampled, num_classes=vocabulary_size))

  # Optimizer.
  # Note: The optimizer will optimize the softmax_weights AND the embeddings.
  # This is because the embeddings are defined as a variable quantity and the
  # optimizer's `minimize` method will by default modify all variable quantities 
  # that contribute to the tensor it is passed.
  # See docs on `tf.train.Optimizer.minimize()` for more details.
  optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

  # Compute the similarity between minibatch examples and all embeddings.
  # We use the cosine distance:
  norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(embeddings), 1, keepdims=True))
  normalized_embeddings = embeddings / norm
  valid_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
    normalized_embeddings, valid_dataset)
  similarity = tf.matmul(valid_embeddings, tf.transpose(normalized_embeddings))
```

Link to the entire code

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1x87Mj35J47vPFclby4qLlBHc77d2XtKc